# C++ Code Issues: Partial Execution and Unexpected Results

Tags: c++, division

I have a problem, I have this code and when I run it, the code starts and tells me to enter numbers, but when I enter them, nothing happens
the code is supposed to show me the elements that divided by 2 give 0 from the vector, but it doesn't do anything(nu sunt elemente pare means there are no elements that divided by 2 give 0.....and numere pare means elements that divided by 2 give 0[image][image]

I expected the two to give me the elements in the vector that are exactly divisible by 2, but the code doesn't give them to me
this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; int n,i,a[100],t;
int main()
{
cout << "n="; cin>>n;
i=1;
do{
cin>>a[i];
if(a[i]%2==0)t++;
}while(i<n||i==n);
i++;
if(t==0){
cout<<"Nu sunt elemente pare.";
}else cout<<t<<" numere pare";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't cram multiple statements into a single line. Don't use global variables. Indent your code. And [`using namespace std;` is a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). `i<n||i==n` is the same as `i <= n`.

Comment: There also no need for an array in your code, all it does in risk going out of bounds.

Comment: And where *inside* your loop do you modify `i`? On that note, remember that array indexes in C++ are *zero* based.

Comment: Side notes: in C++ it is better to use `std::vector<int>` than it is to use a pre-allocated "C" style array to read from an input where you don't know the number of entries up front.  And then you can even use std::count_if to count the elements with certain properties. Also avoid global variables, the variables you have can all be declared within your main function.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you current C++ usually is written differently than what you are learning now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// using namespace std; No don't do this.
// learn to make functions for substeps
std::vector<int> ask_for_values()
{
    int count;
    std::cout << "Enter number of values : ";
    std::cin >> count;

    // create a (dynamic) array with count elements
    // and set all of them to 0
    std::vector<int> values(count,0);

    // range based for loop
    // reading each value from std::cin
    for(auto& value : values)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a value : ";
        std::cin >> value;
    }

    return values;
}

// declare a predicate for odd
// again an extra function helps you describe your intent in code
bool is_odd(int value)
{
    return (value % 2) == 1;
}

int main()
{
    //std::vector values = ask_for_values();
    std::vector values{1,2,5,4,3,9}; // test values

    //don't be afraid to use long variable names ;)
    //std::count_if counts the number of elements for which the predicate holds.
    auto number_of_odd_numbers = std::count_if(values.begin(), values.end(), is_odd );
    std::cout << "Number of odd numbers =  " << number_of_odd_numbers<< "\n";

    return 0;
}
```